# Can't use mypy in command prompt for type checking in Python

Tags: python

I have installed `mypy` via command prompt on `Windows` using this command line:
`python -m pip install mypy`, I'm using `python 3.10.0`, when I use `pip list`, it shows that  I have installed `mypy 0.910` and `mypy-extensions 0.4.3`, but when I use it to check a program `mypy hello.py`, it said `'mypy' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`. Can anyone help me with this? I don't know how to fix this problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does `python -m mypy hello.py` work?

Answer (score 4):

You can try these things

1. Restart your PC. Then try again.
2. Try `pip install mypy==0.910`. Try again.
3. Check whether the location of the pip environment is specified in the Environment variables (`Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings >Environment Variables`). If it is not add it or specify the path manually.

example -: `mypy C:\<your file location>\hello.py`